# Mask String before occurrence of first whitespace

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

I want to mask the string before the first white space 
Eg. "123 test1" mask to xxtest1
      "12/6786 test2" mask to xxtest2
Using string replace all with regex

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this `^.*?[^\s]*\s` and it seems to be working to your case.

Comment: I have tried ([^\s])+ but it's not working

Comment: Have you tried what i provided ? i tried it online and it's perfectly working, see here https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes it's working fine  thanks :)